NextJs <Script> only works when page is reloaded
very new to NextJS and I'm running into a problem with a third-party ebay script I'm trying to display on one of my routes page. It only seems to display sometimes when I reload. When the page is changed to the store page through a link/route, it does not display anything.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong or other method that I can use to fix this? Thank you!
import Script from "next/script";
import Image from "next/image";

const page = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <section className="max-container padding-container flex flex-col gap-20 py-10 md:gap-28 lg:py-20 xl:flex-row">
                {/*rest of code here*/}
            </section>

            <div className="2xl:max-container relative flex flex-col lg:mb-10 lg:py-10 bg-white">
                <Script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://www.auctionnudge.app/feed/item/js/theme/responsive/page/init/img_size/120/cats_output/dropdown/search_
    box/1/blank/1/show_logo/1/lang/english/SellerID/example/siteid/0/MaxEntries/35/sortOrder/StartTimeNewest/target/52d212f5f"
                />
                <div id="auction-nudge-52d212f5f" />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default page;


I've seen other users ask and I tried using the strategy="beforeInteractive" and other methods such as useEffect, but had no luck. I need the script to only load on this specific page so I don't think I can put it in layout.tsx.

I'm not a lot into React, but, maybe, when you have a negative result there is a Error/Warning in a console? Can we see that?

There are no errors in either case, only two unrelated warnings about an image.

The problem is that this script relies on the window load event. That happens only once, when the page loads, if you bind it after the page was already loaded, nothing happens. And NextJs runs the script after the page loads.
The only solution I could come up with was to copy the script and fix that behavior hehe:
Create the file auction-nudge.js file in the public folder with this:
function AN_Item_JS() {

    var AN = null;
    var head = null;
    var request_endpoint = null;
    var request_params = {};
    var container = null;
    var last_js = null;
    var max_pages = null;
    this.init = function (params = {}) {
        AN = this;
        AN.config = {
            target_div_id: 'auction-nudge-items',
            request_params: {},
            template_html: '',
            item_html: '',
            page_active: false,
            page_show_next: false,
            page_show_prev: false,
            cats_output: false,
            search_box: false,
            theme_css_asset: '',
            theme_js_asset: ''
        };
        AN.update_config(params);
        AN.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        AN.request_endpoint = 'https://www.auctionnudge.app/feed/item/js';
        AN.disclosure_html = '<div style="position:initial !important;display:block !important;margin:10px 0 !important;opacity:1 !important;height:initial !important;color:#222 !important;background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;scale:1 !important"><span style="display:inline-block !important;padding:0 3px;border:1px solid black;color:black;font-weight:normal;line-height:1.5em;background:#f5f5f5;border-radius:2px;scale:1 !important">Ad</span>&nbsp;Clicking an item will take you to eBay, who may pay a referral commission if a purchase is made.</div>';

        //AN.listen(window, 'load', AN.ready); //  ######################## COMMENT THIS
        AN.ready(); //  ######################## ADD THIS
    }
    this.update_config = function (params = {}) {
        for (i in params) {
            if (typeof AN.config[i] !== 'undefined') {
                AN.config[i] = params[i];
            }
        }
    }
    this.ready = function () {
        AN.container = document.getElementById(AN.config.target_div_id);
        if (AN.container === null) {
            AN.console_error('Container #' + AN.config.target_div_id + ' not found.');
            return false;
        }
        if (AN.config.request_params.theme !== 'unstyled') {
            if (AN.container.className.indexOf('auction-nudge-items') === -1) {
                AN.container.className += ' ' + 'auction-nudge-items';
            }
            AN.container.className += ' theme-' + AN.config.request_params.theme;
        }
        AN.add_template_html(AN.config.template_html);
        AN.add_item_html(AN.config.item_html);
        if (AN.config.page_active) {
            AN.setup_pagination();
            AN.page_links('next', AN.config.page_show_next);
        }
        if (AN.config.cats_output) {
            AN.setup_cats(AN.config.cats_output);
        }
        if (AN.config.search_box) {
            AN.setup_search();
        }
        if (AN.config.theme_css_asset) {
            AN.add_asset('css', AN.config.theme_css_asset);
        }
        if (AN.config.theme_js_asset) {
            AN.add_asset('js', AN.config.theme_js_asset);
        }
        let skipCheck = ['carousel'];
        if (skipCheck.indexOf(AN.config.request_params.theme) == -1) {
            setInterval(function () {
                AN.check_disclosure();
            }, 2500);
        }
        AN.ready_callback();
    }
    this.update = function (params = {}) {
        AN.update_config(params);
        AN.show_loading(false);
        if (AN.config.item_html) {
            AN.add_item_html(AN.config.item_html);
        } else {
            AN.handle_items_end();
        }
        AN.update_callback(AN.config.page_show_prev, AN.config.page_show_next);
    }
    this.check_disclosure = function () {
        const checkDiv = AN.container.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        if (!checkDiv || checkDiv.innerHTML !== 'Ad') {
            AN.console_error('Affiliate disclosure not found. This is an eBay requirement.');
            AN.container.innerHTML = AN.disclosure_html + AN.container.innerHTML;
        }
    }
    this.console_error = function (text = '') {
        console.log('Auction Nudge Error: ' + text + '');
    }
    this.add_template_html = function (html) {
        if (location.host.indexOf('ebay') != -1 || location.host.indexOf('paypal') != -1) {
            html = '<p><strong>Auction Nudge Error</strong><br />Your items can not load because the website hostname contains a disallowed keyword.</p>';
        }
        AN.container.innerHTML = html;
        AN.item_wrap = AN.container.getElementsByClassName('an-item-wrap')[0];
    }
    this.add_item_html = function (html) {
        AN.item_wrap.innerHTML = html;
    }
    this.create_element = function (type, attr, content) {
        var ele = document.createElement(type);
        for (key in attr) {
            ele.setAttribute(key, attr[key]);
        }
        if (content) {
            if (typeof content == 'object') {
                ele.appendChild(content);
            } else {
                ele.innerHTML = content;
            }
        }
        return ele;
    }
    this.listen = function (ele, event, callback) {
        if (typeof ele !== 'object') {
            AN.console_error('Element not found');
            return false;
        }
        switch (event) {
            case 'load':
                if (typeof ele.addEventListener != "undefined") {
                    ele.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
                } else if (typeof ele.attachEvent != "undefined") {
                    ele.attachEvent("onload", callback);
                } else {
                    if (ele.onload != null) {
                        var old_onload = ele.onload;
                        ele.onload = function (e) {
                            old_onload(e);
                            e[callback]();
                        };
                    } else {
                        ele.onload = callback;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (typeof ele.addEventListener != "undefined") {
                    ele.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
                } else if (typeof ele.attachEvent != "undefined") {
                    ele.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    this.add_asset = function (type, url) {
        var e_type = '';
        switch (type) {
            case 'css':
                e_type = 'link';
                var styles = AN.head.getElementsByTagName(e_type);
                for (i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
                    if (url === styles[i].href) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var attr = {
                    'type': 'text/css',
                    'rel': 'stylesheet',
                    'href': url
                };
                break;
            case 'js':
                e_type = 'script';
                var scripts = AN.head.getElementsByTagName(e_type);
                for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
                    if (url === scripts[i].src) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var attr = {
                    'type': 'text/javascript',
                    'src': url
                };
                break;
        }
        AN.head.appendChild(AN.create_element(e_type, attr, ''));
    }
    this.request_items = function () {
        AN.show_loading(true);
        var request = AN.build_request();
        AN.perform_request(request);
    }
    this.build_request = function () {
        AN.config.request_params.action = 'update';
        var request = AN.request_endpoint;
        for (key in AN.config.request_params) {
            request += '/' + key + '/' + AN.config.request_params[key];
        }
        return request;
    }
    this.perform_request = function (request) {
        if (AN.last_js) {
            AN.head.removeChild(AN.last_js);
        }
        var attr = {
            'type': 'text/javascript',
            'src': request
        };
        var add_js = AN.create_element('script', attr, '');
        AN.head.appendChild(add_js);
        AN.last_js = add_js;
    }
    this.ready_callback = function () {
        if (typeof window.auction_nudge_loaded == 'function') {
            auction_nudge_loaded(AN.config);
        }
    }
    this.update_callback = function (page_show_prev, page_show_next) {
        if (typeof AN.update_pagination == 'function') {
            AN.update_pagination(page_show_prev, page_show_next);
        }
        if (typeof window.an_item_resize == 'function') {
            an_item_resize();
        }
        if (typeof window.auction_nudge_loaded == 'function') {
            auction_nudge_loaded();
        }
    }
    this.show_loading = function (loading) {
        if (loading) {
            AN.container.className += ' an-loading';
        } else {
            AN.container.className = AN.container.className.replace(/( )?an-loading/g, '');
        }
    }
}
var AN_Item_52d212f5f = new AN_Item_JS();
AN_Item_52d212f5f.init({
    target_div_id: 'auction-nudge-52d212f5f',
    request_params: {
        "target": "52d212f5f",
        "action": "init",
        "theme": "responsive",
        "page": "1",
        "img_size": "120",
        "cats_output": "dropdown",
        "search_box": "1",
        "blank": "1",
        "show_logo": "1",
        "lang": "english",
        "SellerID": "example",
        "siteid": "0",
        "MaxEntries": "35",
        "sortOrder": "StartTimeNewest"
    },
    template_html: '<div id=\"\" class=\"an-item-wrap\"></div>',
    item_html: '<p class=\"no-items\">No items found.</p>',
    page_active: false,
    page_show_next: false,
    cats_output: '',
    search_box: false,
    theme_css_asset: '',
    theme_js_asset: ''
});

Use the file:
import Script from "next/script";

const page = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <section className="max-container padding-container flex flex-col gap-20 py-10 md:gap-28 lg:py-20 xl:flex-row">
                {/*rest of code here*/}
            </section>
            <div className="2xl:max-container relative flex flex-col lg:mb-10 lg:py-10 bg-white">
                <Script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src="/auction-nudge.js"
                />
                <div id="auction-nudge-52d212f5f" />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default page;


This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. It looks like the script is loading every time now. The only problem I'm having now is the script is displaying "no items found" when I swap in my SellerID for "example". With my old script, while it only worked on reload, the items were all displaying correctly. Any idea how I can fix this last part? Thanks again!

I think I see the issue, it's with this line: item_html: 'No items found.'. If you put a valid seller ID such as newegg for example you will see that there is data being displayed instead of "No items found."
https://www.auctionnudge.app/feed/item/js/theme/responsive/page/init/img_size/120/cats_output/dropdown/search_box/1/blank/1/show_logo/1/lang/english/SellerID/newegg/siteid/0/MaxEntries/35/target/02d3e5c54

If It didnt work you can open the complete link in the browser, copy the script and and apply same changes

Unfortunately the old problem is back. I've copied the script and it's displaying correctly now, but only when refreshed.

You can't just copy and paste, you need to apply the changes first. To make things easier, put the code in a Javascript beatifier, then remove this line: AN.listen(window, 'load', AN.ready); and add this in its place: AN.ready();

That fixed it, thank you so much. I forgot to add this line :)
